# How to make x11vnc adjust resolution with client display

Tags: linux, vnc, vnc-server

When use x11vnc display:0 to start the vnc server, then client will have exactly the same resolution as server, is that possible to configure x11vnc server (i.e. edit the .x11vncrc file) to make the resolution can be adjusted automatically with the display of client?

And how to make the server show "locked up" on screen when connected by a client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think these two are possible (at least not with x11vnc afaik).

The reason is x11vnc simply copy the content of current screen and send it through vnc. Therefore the vnc and the screen has to be of the same size and show the same thing.

Does your "show locked up" mean just show the word on the screen (I think the vnc server of gnome(forgot the name) has some kind of notification to incomming connections) or to lock the screen?

Answer (score -2):

If you use gnome desktop, take a look at "vino". 
You can find settings at System>Preferences>Remote Desktop. Or you can make settings via Gconf.